# Function of testosterone in women and estrogen in men

Tags: endocrinology, sexual-dimorphism

I was recently surprised to find out that testosterone and estrogen are found in both men and women albeit in different amounts.

I know that testosterone is related to the development of facial, body and pubic hair, deepening of the voice, and muscle development in men.  And that estrogen helps in maintaining the condition of the vaginal lining and its elasticity, and in producing vaginal lubrication in women among other functions.

But what could be the function of testosterone in women or estrogen in men? A simple Google search could give me no good results except for [here](http://health.howstuffworks.com/sexual-health/sexuality/estrogen-and-testosterone-hormones-dictionary1.htm) where it says:

> In men, estrogens have no known function. An unusually high level, however, may reduce sexual appetite, cause erectile difficulties, produce some breast enlargement, and result in the loss of body hair in some men.

and that

> Large deficiencies of testosterone may cause a drop in sexual desire, and excessive testosterone may heighten sexual interest in both sexes.

Does anyone have any further knowledge?

Answer (score 5):

As you know by now, both males and females have testosterone and estradiol. Of course, their levels are different in each sex, but both hormones are important to males and females. A human male with zero blood concentration of estradiol or a human female with zero blood concentration of testosterone wouldn't be possible.

Here are some famous examples:

**Role of testosterone in human females:**

1. Increase libido<sup>[1](http://www.psyneuen-journal.com/article/S0306-4530(03)00161-6/abstract),[2](http://www.nature.com/ijir/journal/v17/n5/full/3901334a.html)</sup>
2. Modulate physiology of vaginal tissue<sup>[3](http://www.fertstert.org/article/S0015-0282(02)02978-3/abstract)</sup>

**Role of estradiol in human males:**

1. Help to regulate spermatogenesis<sup>[4](http://rbej.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1477-7827-1-35)</sup>
2. Reduce bone loss<sup>[5](http://www.eje-online.org/content/160/6/883.full)</sup>